# How are CMD and ENTRYPOINT exec forms in a docker file parsed?

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I am running Jupyter in a Docker container. The following shell form will run fine:

```
CMD jupyter lab --ip='0.0.0.0' --port=8888 --no-browser --allow-root /home/notebooks
```

But the following one on docker file will not:

```
ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/sh", "-c"]
CMD ["jupyter", "lab", "--ip='0.0.0.0'", "--port=8888", "--no-browser", "--allow-root", "/home/notebooks"]
```

The error is:

```
usage: jupyter [-h] [--version] [--config-dir] [--data-dir] [--runtime-dir] [--paths] [--json] [subcommand]
jupyter: error: one of the arguments --version subcommand --config-dir --data-dir --runtime-dir --paths is required
```

So obviously `/bin/sh -c` sees the `jupyter` argument, but not the following ones.

Interestingly,

```
CMD ["jupyter", "lab", "--ip='0.0.0.0'", "--port=8888", "--no-browser", "--allow-root", "/home/notebooks"]
```

will run fine, so it cannot be the number of arguments, or can it?

According to https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#cmd, the shell form of CMD executes with `/bin/sh -c`. So from my point of view I see little difference in the 2 versions. But the reason must be how the exec forms are being evaluated when ENTRYPOINT and CMD are present at the same time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At a very low level, Linux commands are executed as a series of "words".  Typically your shell will take a command line like `ls -l "a directory"` and breaks that into three words `ls` `-l` `a directory`.  (Note the space in "a directory": in the shell form that needs to be quoted to be in the same word.)

The Dockerfile `CMD` and `ENTRYPOINT` (and `RUN`) commands have two forms.  In the form you've specified that looks like a JSON array, you are explicitly specifying how the words get broken up.  If it doesn't look like a JSON array then the whole thing is taken as a single string, and wrapped in an `sh -c` command.

```sh
# Explicitly spelling out the words
RUN ["ls", "-l", "a directory"]

# Asking Docker to run it via a shell
RUN ls -l 'a directory'
# The same as
RUN ["sh", "-c", "ls -l 'a directory'"]
```

If you [specify both `ENTRYPOINT` and `CMD`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#understand-how-cmd-and-entrypoint-interact) the two lists of words just get combined together.  The important thing for your example is that `sh -c` takes *the single next word* and runs it as a shell command; any remaining words can be used as `$0`, `$1`, ... positional arguments within that command string.

So in your example, the final thing that gets run is more or less

```sh
ENTRYPOINT+CMD ["sh", "-c", "jupyter", ...]
# If the string "jupyter" contained "$1" it would expand to the --ip option
```

The other important corollary to this is that, practically, `ENTRYPOINT` can't be the bare-string format: when the `CMD` is appended to it you get

```sh
ENTRYPOINT some command
CMD with args

ENTRYPOINT+CMD ["sh", "-c", "some command", "sh", "-c", "with args"]
```

and by the same rule all of the `CMD` words get ignored.

In practice you almost never need to explicitly put `sh -c` or a `SHELL` declaration in a Dockerfile; use a string-form command instead, or put complex logic into a shell script.

Comment: Thanks David for this very clear explanation. Wish `https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#entrypoint` would explain that particular point. My main takeaway: `sh -c` from ENTRYPOINT "**takes the single next word and runs it as a shell command**; any remaining words can be used as $0, $1, ... positional arguments within that command string", i.e. the command string needs to be `command $1 $2 $3 [...]` to "inject" the other words from CMD into the shell command.